# Using argparse on a 1000+ line text file to filter and work on lines that start with a certain word

Tags: python, argparse

First off, I'm sorry ahead of time if I seem clueless. I knew literally nothing about programming before a week ago but now that I've seen how valuable of a skill it is, I'd like to learn how to do some of the things the programmer in our science lab. Anyways, enough background.

One of the most useful programs he came up with takes a pdb file (essentially a large, 1000+ line text file) and filters for only the lines that begin with a certain word depending on what he wants to look at. Each line has the same format/length so that should make it easier. After filtering for those words, he pulls out the data associated with that line and performs calculations with it. An example line would be:

```
ATOM       1  N   MET A   1      36.886  53.177 ... (more data)
```

So my question is this: he suggested looking at argparse to help the filtering but I cannot for the life of me understand the argparse help or tutorials. Is this possible and if so can you wonderful people maybe help point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Ah yes I went through the CodeAcademy Python tutorial throughout the last week but argparse was just so unlike everything I had seen there. Thanks though! Definitely plan to keep practicing the basics

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** This answer does not pertain to the question of *how to scan a PDB file for keyword*, but basically illustrates *what `argparse` package can do*.

When your friend said that argparse will "help to filter the PDB file ", it is more about helping to create a program that is more user friendly to filter the PDB file.

Without `argparse`, people can write code like:

```
import sys

keyword = sys.argv[2]
pdb_file = sys.argv[1]    

# and then go on using it, say you already have a PDB file scanning function
search_pdb_with_keyword(pdb_file, keyword)
```

And if the user tries to use your Python script without specifying any arguments, he or she gets:

```
$ python pdb_search.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdb_search.py", line 3, in <module>
    keyword = sys.argv[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This error may be confusing and not helpful at all for the user unless he knows a bit about Python. And even with this error, the user has no clue about:

- how many arguments does your program take
- what are the positions of the arguments
- what types of arguments are acceptable.

You can (slightly) improve above bad practice by writing some simple validation:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    pdb_file = sys.argv[1]
    keyword = sys.argv[2]
    if keyword not in ("ATOM", "HETATM"):
        print("Invalid keyword!", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1) # abort
    if not os.path.exists(pdb_file):
        print("File {} does not exist.".format(pdb_file), file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
else:
    print("Usage: {} <pdb_file> <ATOM|HETATM>", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

search_pdb_with_keyword(pdb_file, keyword)
```

Imagine if you have multiple arguments, each of which has its own specific requirements, then you end up with writing a lot of `if` clauses and that's tedious and error-prone.
So there comes `argparse` for you to define what arguments your program accepts and how should `argparse` validates them.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser(description="PDB keyword search program.")
parser.add_argument("pdb_file", type=file, help="A PDB file as input.")
parser.add_argument("keyword", choices=("ATOM", "HETATM"), help="Keyword to search for")

# argparse will validate the user's arguments for you, checking if two arguments are 
# specified and if the first argument is an existing file and if the second argument
# is either ATOM or HETATM
args = parser.parse_args()

search_pdb_with_keyword(args.pdb_file, args.keyword)
```

If the user ran the program incorrectly, say

```
$ python pdb_search.py pdb_file   # lacking the keyword
```

an error will popup:

```
$ python pdb_search.py

usage: pdb_search.py [-h] pdb_file {ATOM,HETATM}
pdb_search.py: error: too few arguments
```

It suggests how many arguments your program takes and what they are.

It will even format the usage information for you:

```
$ python pdb_search.py -h

usage: pdb_search.py [-h] pdb_file {ATOM,HETATM}

PDB keyword search program.

positional arguments:
  pdb_file       A PDB file as input.
  {ATOM,HETATM}  Keyword to search for

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
```

But you should really [read the `argparse` documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) if you want to know more about how to use it and how does it pertain to your use case here.

And you can take other people's answer as an implementation for the dummy function `search_pdb_with_keyword` I have in my code.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's some confusion here.

Argparse is a library included with Python that lets you take in and easily handle command line parameters -- basically, they make it easier for you to create an interface that other people can use when running your program.

The task of filtering the text file is completely orthogonal to what argparse does. If it helps, you can think of argparse as a way of getting info and configuration options before running your program. The task of actually filtering is something you'll have to write on your own.

Don't know what the command line is? Here's a [good intro](http://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/command-line/). Here's a [tutorial](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/) on how to use the command line.

Comment: Oh okay that makes a lot more sense. Yeah I went through the Python tutorial at CodeAcademy but this was just so unlike what was taught there. That does make more sense, but then why would he suggest I use it? I assume the program I would write includes an if/elif/else kind of loop that will loop through looking for my words and pulling that line out into a list?

Comment: @Ryan -- I'm not sure why he suggested it. My guess is that he might have been suggesting something different then what you remember, or that there was some misunderstanding/miscommunication. Do you happen to know EXACTLY what your friend said to you? If you can edit your question and paste a verbatim transcript, I can try and interpret what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html):

> The `argparse` module makes it easy to write user-friendly command-line interfaces. The program defines what arguments it requires, and argparse will figure out how to parse those out of sys.argv.

There are better alternatives to parse files in python. For example you could:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('ATOM'):
            print line
```

If you want to check for multiple keywords consider the module [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) that checks for [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
import re

keywords = ['ATOM', 'TOM', 'OM']
pattern = re.compile('^(?:' + '|'.join(keywords) + ').*$', re.MULTILINE)

with open('DATA', 'r') as f:
    for line in pattern.findall(f.read()):
        print line
```